# Display a preview of the website

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, messaging

I need to display a preview of the website with given `url` in the single image(e.g. like `Facebook` do in `Messenger` when you sending a `url` to someone). Is there any way to achieve that without actually loading the `html file` and reading it's `metadata`?

Comment: Probably need to use an API service like https://screenshotlayer.com

Comment: Check my answer and take look at a link posted in answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
NSString *urlStr = @"http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString: urlStr];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];


UIImageView *imagview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];

imagview.frame = CGRectMake(250, 500, 100, 100);

[self.view addSubview:imagview];
```

This will give just thumb or image.
You can use [URLEmbeddedView Library](https://github.com/marty-suzuki/URLEmbeddedView) for more functionality. I think this is the library what you want.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that calling `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]` on the main thread is a bad idea and should generally be avoided.

Comment: It can be done asynchronously, It is just demonstration that how it can be achieved!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I need is actually to get an open graph image url of the given web page url. URLEmbeddedView library is doing that but it have a lot of unnecessary functionality, do you know an easier way or a lighter lib to do that?